# Printing out student averages with file input using string tokenizer and scanner

Tags: java, file-io, stringtokenizer

I am trying to get the averages of values in a text file. The content of the file is:

> Agnes 56 82 95 100 68 52 
>     Bufford 87 92 97 100 96 85 93 77 98 86 
>     Julie 99 100 100 89 96 100 92 99 68 
>     Alice 40 36 85 16 0 22 72 
>     Bobby 100 98 92 86 88

I have to skip the names, and try to sum the values of the integers of each line. The ouput should be something like this:

> Agnes, average = 76 
>     Bufford, average = 91 
>     Julie, average = 94 
>     Alice, average = 39 
>     Bobby, average = 93

My problem is that i am unable to sum the values (using sum+=sc1.nextInt()). I also cant count the number of tokens of just the integers. For example, for the first line I need countTokens to equal 6, but i get 7, even after I skip the name.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
public class studentAverages
{
public static void main() throws IOException
{
    Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Name\\StudentScores.in"));
    int maxIndex = -1; 
    String text[] = new String[100]; 
    while(sf.hasNext( ))
    {
        maxIndex++;
        text[maxIndex] = sf.nextLine();
    }
    sf.close();

    int sum=0;
    int avg=0;
    int divisor=0;
    for (int i=0;i<=maxIndex; i++)
    {
        StringTokenizer sc= new StringTokenizer(text[i]);
        Scanner sc1= new Scanner (text[i]);

        while (sc1.hasNext())
        {
            sc1.useDelimiter(" ");
            sc1.skip("\\D*");                
            System.out.print(sc1.nextInt());
            System.out.println(sc1.nextLine());
            sum+=sc1.nextInt(); // trying to sum all the numbers in each line, tried putting this line everywhere
            avg=sum/divisor;
            break;
        }            
        System.out.println(avg);
        while (sc.hasMoreTokens())
        {         
            divisor=sc.countTokens()-1; //Not able to count tokens of just the numbers, thats why I am using -1 
            //System.out.println(divisor);
            break;
        }
    }
    //this is for the output 
    /*for (int i=0; i<=maxIndex; i++)
    {
        String theNames="";
        Scanner sc= new Scanner (text[i]);
        theNames=sc.findInLine("\\w*");
        System.out.println(theNames + ", average = ");
    }*/
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("resources/abc.txt"));
    //check for next line
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        //create new scanner for each line to read string and integers
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
        //read name
        String name = scanner1.next();
        double total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        //read all the integers
        while (scanner1.hasNextInt()) {
            total += scanner1.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(name + ", average = " + (total / count));
    }
    scanner.close();
```

output:

```
Agnes, average = 75.5
Bufford, average = 91.1
Julie, average = 93.66666666666667
Alice, average = 38.714285714285715
Bobby, average = 92.8
```

---

--EDIT--

Here is the code as per your last comment (I have to use StringTokenizer`/string methods like useDelimiter, skip, etc to arrive at the answer)

```
    Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("resources/abc.txt"));
    List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sf.hasNext()) {
        text.add(sf.nextLine());
    }
    sf.close();

    for (String str : text) {
        StringTokenizer sc = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String name = sc.nextToken();
        while (sc.hasMoreElements()) {
            sum += Integer.valueOf(sc.nextToken());
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(name + ", average = " + (sum / count));
    }
}
```

output

```
Agnes, average = 75.5
Bufford, average = 91.1
Julie, average = 93.66666666666667
Alice, average = 38.714285714285715
Bobby, average = 92.8
```

Comment: Well this was a nice and simple solution! It works out well, but i have to use StringTokenizer/string methods like useDelimiter, skip, etc to arrive at the answer. Any tips?

Comment: Why do you want to use only `StringTokenizer`? It's possible by using `Scanner` that you are already using. **KEEP the things SIMPLE**.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend splitting each line using the `split` method and then looping through those values while ignoring the first, because you know that is the title.

```
public static void main() throws IOException {
    Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("C:\\temp_Name\\StudentScores.in"));
    int maxIndex = -1; 
    String text[] = new String[100]; 

    while(sf.hasNext( )) {
        maxIndex++;
        text[maxIndex] = sf.nextLine();
    }

    sf.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i ++) {
        String[] values = text[i].split(" ");
        String title = values[0];
        int sum = 0;

        for(int j = 1; i < values.length; j ++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(values[j]);
        }

        double average = sum / (values.length - 1);
        System.out.println(title + ": " + average);
    }
}
```

Notice that the inner loop's index begins at 1 and not 0, and that when calculating the average, we subtract one from the size of the `values` array because we want to ignore the title.

Comment: This also works, but I need to use string methods/string tokenizer to arrive at the answer